# Java Flow.Subscriber - How can I get the publisher of onComplete?

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, java-9, java.util.concurrent, java-flow

I'm creating an user event system using JDK 9 Flow API, so I have a room (which extends the `UserSubscriver` class above), it may have many users and each user can offer (dispatch) updates at any time.

```
public abstract class UserSubscriver implements Flow.Subscriber<Notification> {
    private Flow.Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(final Flow.Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(final Notification notification) {
        // ...
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        // How can I know who was the publisher of this?
    }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User extends SubmissionPublisher<Notification> {

    ....

    public int offer(Notification item) {
        return super.offer(item, (sub, msg) -> false);
    }
}
```

On the `onUpdate` I can receive any args, so I can receive the publisher of the update, but there are no args on `onComplete`.

How can I know who was the publisher of an `onComplete` event?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. A `Flow.Subscriber` should not be reused to observe multiple sources directly. You can create `Flow.Subscriber`s to each individual `Flow.Publisher` or merge the `Publisher`s into one flow (currently not supported by juc.Flow) and have the value type emitted to be a pair of the `Publisher`'s identity and the value it wants to send you.

Comment: @akarnokd thank you for your comment, I'm trying to figure out what am I doing wrong and what is your suggestion. Basically I have a room, any user can enter it, and when some one does, I want to start listening for updates from that user, I was previously using Observers, but it's deprecated in Java9. In my current system, my room `implements Flow.Subscriber<Notification>` and my user `extends SubmissionPublisher<Notification>`. What do you suggest me to change? Thank you!

Comment: You should perhaps look at any feature-rich reactive library first: [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) and [Reactor-Core](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core) for example.

Comment: Thank you @akarnokd, I'll have a look on those. I can work around this problem, but do you think it's really a bad idea to use Flow?

Comment: Depends on the problem you are trying to solve. Is this something you are using to learn reactive programming or there is a real world problem behind it with true asynchronous services and such? Is Java 9 a requirement? The Java 9 Flow API is intended as an interoperation API aimed at library writers primarily.

Comment: This is a socket server, with clients which may be distributed in many rooms, this doesn't need to much accuracy. I just need the events, I started the migration because of the Observers deprecation. It's not a mandatory migration but if it's deprecated, it may have issues and bugs, and soon will be discontinued, so I thought it would be a good idea to avoid future problems, and do this now.